# Validity check of inherited and internal members within a S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4

I extend the basic R-type array with the following S4 class:

```
setClass("marray",
  representation(
    shape = "integer",
    ndim = "integer",
    size = "integer",
    order = "character"
  ),
  prototype(
    ... # some default values
  ),
  contains = "array"
)
```

Within a class method I will set the dimension of the array:

```
setMethod("reshape",
  signature = "marray",
  definition = function(object, dim = NULL, order = c("C", "F") {
    order <- match.arg(order)
    if (identical(object@shape, dim) && identical(object@order, order))
      return(object)
    if ((identical(object@shape, dim)) && (!identical(object@order, order)))
      object <- flatten(object, axis = NULL, order = object@order)
    if (identical(order, "C"))
      dimC(object@.Data) <- dim
    else
      dim(object@.Data) <- dim
    if (is.null(dim)) object@.Data <- as.array(object@.Data)
    object@shape <- as.integer(DIM(object@.Data))
    object@ndim <- as.integer(length(object@shape))
    object@size <- as.integer(prod(object@shape))
    object@order <- order
    object
  }
)
```

If dim is NULL, the following error occurred: "Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass) : Assignment of an object of class integer in an object of class marray is not allowed for @.Data"

I can understand the error, but what is a proper way to get rid of it?

With this workaround within the method everything works pretty fine:

```
data <- object@.Data
dim(data) <- dim
object@.Data <- as.array(data)
```

My feeling tells me that this workaround is not necessarily the best way to get around this problem. Saving the array (.Data) in a variable (data) and afterwards restoring it back seems to me a huge memory issue.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the full code for the reshape method? The error might be in one of the `...` parts.

Comment: Thanks! I've completed the code, please see above. Some hints: flatten() is a function that flattens a n-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array setting dim equal NULL. DIM() is a function which encapsulates the operator '%||%' <- function(x, y) { if (is.null(x)) y else x } like: DIM <- function(x) { dim(x) %||% length(x) }.

Comment: Thanks --- I'm not going to forensically debug it, but the error is telling you that one of the lines that begins `object <- ` is assigning something into `object` which is not an `array`. With S4 classes, if you extend a class the `@.Data` slot must always be from the class you are extending (here `array`). If it ever isn't , that's an error. It seems like the `flatten` call is just returning a `vector` which isn't an `array`, so that would seem to be the problem. Perhaps setting the `dim` to nx1x1x... would work?

Comment: And thanks again! That was my thought too. I'v created a new ClassUnion consisting of array, integer, numeric etc. Inside representation I use a field named Data with that union type. And now everything works fine.